# Showing $F(f)=\sin(f)$ is Continuous

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

We have a Banach Space $C[0,1]$; consider a function $F:C[0,1]\to C[0,1]$, where

$$(F(f))(t):=\sin(f(t))$$

and this is $\forall t\in [0,1]$

Prove F is continuous.

I tried showing that F was a contaction, so then in a Banach Space, which is complete, this would insinuate that F is uniformly continuous, which is a stronger condition than I need to show.

Maybe I'm approaching the question incorrectly, any tips?  Thanks

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is easier than it sounds. Note that $|\sin x-\sin y| = |\int_x^y \cos t dt| \leq |x-y|$ for all $x\leq y \in \mathbb{R}$. In particular for any $f,g \in C[0,1],$ we have $ |\sin f(t)- \sin g(t)| \leq |f(t)-g(t)|$ for all $t \in [0,1]$, so 
$$
||F(f)-F(g)|| = \max_{0\leq t \leq 1} |\sin f(t)-\sin g(t)| \leq \max_{0 \leq t \leq 1} | f(t)-g(t)| = ||f-g||
$$
which implies that $F$ is Lipschitz continuous (clearly stronger than continuous).

Thanks to Joonas who pointed out that my original answer only showed continuity at $f=0$.

Comment: I don't exactly see where this is going but it is a good start to know that the function is bounded for all t!  Seems pretty obvious.  Im trying to use convergent sequences and what not.  With what you said I think knowing that all cauchy sequences is convergent is important.  I'll keep working!

Comment: This shows that $F$ is a contraction since $||F(f)|| =\max \sin f(t)| \leq \max |f(t)| =  ||f||$.

Comment: I'm allowed to assume that the norm is what you made it equal to always?  This really was simple though thanks!

Comment: When one speaks of $C[0,1]$ if one does not specify a norm, one is implicitly assuming the maximum norm is taken.

Comment: It's not that easy. You have shown that $F$ is continuous at the zero function. The mapping $F$ is not linear, so this is not enough. It's not hard to modify the proof, though: $\|F(f)-F(g)\|\leq\|f-g\|$ since $\sin$ is 1-Lipschitz.

Comment: You're welcome. :) In general, if $\phi:\mathbb R\to\mathbb R$ is uniformly continuous, then $F$ defined by $F(f)(x)=\phi(f(x))$ inherits the modulus of continuity from $\phi$.